# sql COUNT function returns an array instead of mysqli object?

Tags: sql, mysql, arrays, object

I want to count some rows in my database and I'm using the following code:

```
                $tagname = Person;
                $query = "SELECT COUNT(thread_tag_map.tag_id) AS tagcount
                        FROM tags, thread_tag_map
                        WHERE thread_tag_map.tag_id = tags.id
                        AND tags.name = '$tagname'";

                $result = $this->do_query($query);


                return $result;
```

When I use print_r($result) it shows an associative array Array ( [tagcount] => 3 ).

Shouldn't it be a mysqli object that I have to extract using mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Could someone explain?

Comment: You do realize that you're using the do_query() method of the $this object that we know nothing about right ? Tell us what framework/class/... it is if you want us to help you.

Comment: If this is mysqli why is your query not using a prepared statement?  Your wrist should be slapped for opening yourself up to a potential SQL injection with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count returns just a number, but you are executing a sql select statement and this will return something like a rowset, i.e. a bunch of rows (in your case 1) with an element for each column (in you case 1).

The exact details depend on the programming language an api you are using.

Comment: how should i write the code to just return a nr? i want to return a count on duplicate rows of thread_tag_map.tag_id

Comment: In principle: take the first element of the result set, extract the single value, from the associative array. I have no idea about the exact syntax since I don't even know the language you are using. This would be a good new question